# Get the related entity crm

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have two entities on the CRM Organization "Template" and "Product" with a relationship 1:N. A "Template" can be related to multiple "Product", I want to get all the "Product" related to a "Template" using C#.

Ex:

> Template1 is related to three Products P1,P2 and P3. I want to retrive the P1,P2 and P3 when I retrive the Template1 entity. I want the related entity.

Comment: What are you currently doing?

Comment: In addition to @JamesWood, I'd like to know what the exact question is. I gave an answer below but it was a bit of a shot in the dark.

Comment: @JamesWood By the way James, I'm about to woosh past you in reputation. If it wouldn't be for the rep cap, I think I'd be past 3k already. Had a couple of good days, hehe.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, it's the other way around. It's the three instances of the entity *Product*, i.e. *P1*, *P2* and *P3*, that are linked to your instance of entity Template, i.e. *Template1*.

What technique are you going to use to fetch those? In C#, I'd go with *QueryExpression* (but some people would prefer using fetch XML). In JavaScript, I'd make a REST call to the *OrganizationData* web service. From GUI, advanced search (I think, at least, since I'm not commonly working using the GUI).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Konrad's answer, you can also use LINQ to CRM.  If you've used LINQ in the past, I'd recommend that since Query Expressions can be kind of verbose.